# savWriter writerows with Dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, spss

I am trying to use the savReaderWriter library with Python. I have a dataframe which is read in via `df = pd.read_csv`. However using the following piece of code it won't seem to write the rows to the file.

```
with savReaderWriter.SavWriter(savFileName, *args) as writer:
writer.writerows(df)
```

I am getting the following error TypeError: 'str' object does not support item assignment.Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the sample on https://pythonhosted.org/savReaderWriter/

```
savFileName = 'someFile.sav'
records = [[b'Test1', 1, 1], [b'Test2', 2, 1]]
varNames = ['var1', 'v2', 'v3']
varTypes = {'var1': 5, 'v2': 0, 'v3': 0}
with savReaderWriter.SavWriter(savFileName, varNames, varTypes) as writer:
    for record in records:
        writer.writerow(record)
```

I think you can divide you DataFrame into 3 fields(records, varNames, varTypes)
By the way, you can use method in pandas to write data into file.

```
import pandas as pd

sensor_values = pd.DataFrame([[1,'aaa','bbb'],[2,'ppp','xxx']], columns=['A','B','C']) 
varNames=sensor_values.columns
records = sensor_values.values
varType = {key: 0 for x, key in enumerate(sensor_values.columns)}
```

Comment: I need to write the data in a sav file for use in SPSS so .to_csv would not help. How can you divide a dataframe into those 3 fields?

Comment: I have modify my answer, you can use the same way on your DataFrame.